# Why is this linked list returning null? Java

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Here is my code. It is supposed to put integers into a linked list until the user enters -1. It does that fine, but at the end it prints nothing. I don't see why the integers aren't being properly stored in the list.

```
public static Node read(Scanner scan)
{
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    Node n = new Node();
    if (i == -1)
    {
        return n;
    } else {
        n.data = i;
        n = n.next;
        read(scan);
        return n;
    }
}

private static void printlist(Node head) 
{
    if(head == null)
    {}
    else
    {
        System.out.print(head.data + " ");
        printlist(head.next);
        ...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Node head = read(scan);
    printlist(head);
}
```

I added the main and print methods as requested. I also noticed that I am creating a new `Node` in my recursive read method.

How do I declare the node in the read method while also not making an extra node?

Comment: post the whole code and the main method

Comment: Your recursion creates `new Node();`!!

Comment: Yeah, also please post where you are trying to print yous list.

Answer (score 2):

```
n = n.next
```

What is the value of n.next at this point? Why are you setting your new node n to this? My guess is that your problem lies here, and that you're actually trying to set a previous node's "next" value to the new node n. Does this sound right?

Comment: I think. Basically I want to make a new node so that it can be filled by the next scan.nextInt(); call. If I take that line out will my Node n = new Node(); do that?

Comment: Check out Rikayan's solution. It begins by grabbing the user-entered value and creating a new node. If the int is a valid value to be entered into the list (i != -1), the new node takes on the int as its value. The next thing that happens (and this is key) is that its own "next" value is set to the return value of a recursive invocation of the "read()" method, which returns a separate node created from the next value that the user enters (since read() returns a new node).

Answer (score 2):

David pointed out the problem. You can resolve it in this way:

```
public static Node read(Scanner scan)
{
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    Node n = new Node();
    if (i == -1)
    {
        return null;
    } else {
        n.data = i;
        n.next=read(scan); //you probably wanted to do this
        return n;
    }
}
```